# Custom block style not working in the editor

Tags: css, block-editor

I'm using the following code to register a custom block style for the quote block in a child theme:

```
function child_init() {
    register_block_style(
        'core/quote',
        array(
            'name'  => 'big-text-quote',
            'label' => __( 'Big Text Quote', 'textdomain' ),
            'style_handle' => 'child-block-styles',
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'child_init' );

function child_enqueue_block_assets() {
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'child-block-styles',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/blocks.css',
    );
}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_assets', 'child_enqueue_block_assets' );
```

According to the official WP docs, the `enqueue_block_assets` hook should enqueue the `blocks.css` file in both the frontend and the editor but, for some reason, the styles are not loaded in the editor.

I tried the `enqueue_block_editor_assets` hook to load the file in just the editor, but it's not doing anything:

```
function child_enqueue_block_editor_assets() {
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'child-block-styles',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/blocks.css',
    );
}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'child_enqueue_block_editor_assets' );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On the network tab of the browser can you see block.css being downloaded?

Comment: I see the file in the network tab after deleting the browser cache and checking the source code I see: `<link rel="stylesheet" id="child-block-styles-css" href="https://example.com/wp-content/themes/childtheme/assets/css/blocks.css?ver=6.2" media="all">`

Comment: Then the code is working. There must be something wrong with the actual styles.

Comment: If you inspect an element that's supposed to use your custom styles, (1) does the block have the style class, such as `is-style-big-text-quote`, on it? And (2) if you look in the styles pane, can you see your custom styles being overridden? Getting your styles to have the right specificity and load order can be a pain.